# how to get jQuery Full Calendar events to show

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar, momentjs

i am building an intranet site using ASP.Net, C#, and the javascript library "jQuery full calendar" . I have the basic requirements according to the documentation but I think I may either have the scripts out of order or am missing something as the calendar renders but does not show the events listed. I am specifically looking for the holiday events to show as they do on my google calendar.

[link to documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/installation)

below is some relevant code from my master page and I can include the whole masterpage if necessary.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='Content/fullcalendar.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='Content/fullcalendar.print.css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src='Scripts/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='Scripts/jquery.min.js'></script> 
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src='Scripts/gcal.js'></script>
<script src='Scripts/fullcalendar.js'></script> 
<script src='Scripts/Site.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            editable: true,
            disableDragging: true,
            disableResizing: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            googleCalendarApiKey: 'my api key',
            events: function(start, end, callback) {
        // do some asynchronous ajax
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            $.getJSON("/outlookHolidayCalendar2018.JSON",
                    {
                            start: dateFormat(start.getTime()),
                            end: dateFormat(end.getTime())
                    },
                    function(result) {
                            if(result != null)
                            {
                                for (i in result) {
                                    var calEvent = result[i];
                                    //calEvent.date = new Date(parseInt(calEvent.date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
                                    //calEvent.start = new Date(parseInt(calEvent.start.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
                                    //calEvent.end = new Date(parseInt(calEvent.end.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));

                                    title: result.Subject;
                                    start: result.StartDate.format();
                                    end: result.EndDate.format()

                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                alert('there was an error while fetching JSON events!');
                            }
                            var calevents = result;
                            // then, pass the CalEvent array to the callback
                            callback(calevents);

                    });

            },
            eventClick : function(event) {
                editEventShow(event);
            },
            dayClick : function(dayDate){
                addEventShow(dayDate, this);
            }
        });

      });
    </script>
```

my "Calendar" page looks like this.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<%-- using fullcalendar from  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/intro --%>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

below is a sample from my JSON file

```
{
"Subject": "Easter Day",
"StartDate": "4/1/2018",
"StartTime": "12:00:00 AM",
"EndDate": "4/2/2018",
"EndTime": "12:00:00 AM",
"All_day_event": "TRUE",
"Reminder_on_off": "FALSE",
"ReminderDate": "3/31/2018",
"ReminderTime": "11:45:00 PM",
"MeetingOrganizer": "",
"RequiredAttendees": "",
"OptionalAttendees": "",
"MeetingResources": "",
"BillingInformation": "",
"Categories": "",
"Description": "",
"Location": "United States",
"Mileage": "",
"Priority": "Normal",
"Private": "FALSE",
"Sensitivity": "Normal",
"Show_time_as": 3
```

},

here is a screen shot of how it renders:
[image]

can any of you fine ppl help me out?

Comment: Side note: `<link rel='stylesheet' href='Content/fullcalendar.print.css' />` needs to be `<link rel='stylesheet' href='Content/fullcalendar.print.css' media='print'/>` otherwise you'll always get the "print" layout of fullCalendar in the webpage rather than the web version. Google "CSS media queries" if you don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in your browser's console I anticipate you'll have an error or two.

```
title: result.Subject;
start: result.StartDate.format();
end: result.EndDate.format()
```

is wrong - it doesn't do anything useful. I see what you were trying to do (i.e. set field names which match fullCalendar's expected event structure) but for this to work you'd need to actually create an object.

Unfortunately, having done that you then compound the problem by writing `var calevents = result;` - so you just put the raw whole result array into calEvents, ignoring all your attempts at processing it to match fullCalendar's expectations.

Then there is `StartDate.format()`...

Why is this a problem? Because your data is parsed from your JSON.  In your JSON `StartDate` and `EndDate` are strings (representing dates, but strings nonetheless). Therefore in your `result` array, they will still be strings. Strings don't have a `format()` method. Your code will crash because of this (apart from all the other issues!).

FullCalendar (which uses momentJS to deal with dates) can accept dates in a number of ways (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/moment and https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/ for more details).

It can accept dates as a string, but not in the format you provided - it's ambiguous. "4/1/2018" could be 1st April or 4th January depending on how you read it - and usually how you read it depends on the conventions of the country where you live. The computer however cannot be sure which one you intended, unless you tell it.

So, you have two options:

---

Option 1)

If you can't/won't change the JSON source data for any reason, then You have to create an event object (or modify the existing ones) which has field names and formats matching fullCalendar's. You need to set the correct properties, and also use momentJS to parse the date, if you tell it the format the date is in:

```
events: function(start, end, callback) {
  // do some asynchronous ajax
  $.getJSON("/outlookHolidayCalendar2018.JSON", function(result) {
   for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      result[i].title = result[i].Subject;
      result[i].start = moment(result[i].StartDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
      result[i].end = moment(result[i].EndDate, "MM/DD/YYYY")
    }
    callback(result);
  });
},
```

Notes:

a. fullCalendar can accept a momentJS object as input, so there's no need to use `.format()` to change it back into a string again.

b. Your `for` syntax was totally wrong - that's the syntax for iterating object proeprties, not array indexes. And `result` is the whole array, not the individual item.

c. The `if` statement was a bit redundant. Returning no results doesn't indicate an error, it just indicates there were no results. If there are no results, then no events will show on the calendar, that's all. It's not an error or bug.

d. Sending the "start" and "end" parameters in your $.getJSON request is useless because you're accessing a static JSON file. Sending these parameters is only useful if you're sending the request to a server-side script which can process them and use them to restrict the range of the data which is returned to fullCalendar. Therefore I removed them from my example.

---

Option 2)

A cleaner option is to change your JSON so it outputs date strings in an unambiguous format. fullCalendar and momentJS accept date strings in the international standard IS0-8601 format, the date part of which is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, e.g. `2018-04-01`. At this point it would also be sensible to combine the date and time fields into one, because fullCalendar will read a single date/time string for the start and end. Then you don't have to combine them later. The example you gave is marked as an all-day event, so that doesn't apply but that would be the pattern to follow for other events.

In fact if you do a small overhaul of your JSON you can get it into a state where you don't need to process it at all using JavaScript and can just pass it directly to fullCalendar as-is.

Write an event in the JSON like this:

```
{
  "title": "Easter Day",
  "start": "2018-04-01",
  "end": "2018-04-02",
  "allDay": true,
  "Reminder_on_off": false,
  "ReminderDate": "2018-03-31 23:45:00",
  "MeetingOrganizer": "",
  "RequiredAttendees": "",
  "OptionalAttendees": "",
  "MeetingResources": "",
  "BillingInformation": "",
  "Categories": "",
  "Description": "",
  "Location": "United States",
  "Mileage": "",
  "Priority": "Normal",
  "Private": false,
  "Sensitivity": "Normal",
  "Show_time_as": 3
},
```

and then in your JavaScript you can simply write:

```
events: "/outlookHolidayCalendar2018.JSON"
```

and get rid of that whole function, because the field names and formats of the title, start, end and allDay fields are as per what fullCalendar expects (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object).

---

P.S. Your "googleCalendarAPIKey" option and the "contentType" line also both appear to be redundant. The first is useless because you're not accessing a google calendar in your code, and the second just doesn't go anywhere, it's just declared  (incorrectly anyway as if it were an object property) and then discarded. You can also remove the `gcal.js` script because that's only for downloading from Google calendars as well.

Based on all this I think the most important thing you need to do right now is study JavaScript syntax in more detail and also learn how to use your browser's Developer Tools (containing the console and other tools) to debug your programs and look for errors.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. it seems I had a lot of errors there. I actually tried your solution 1 and 2 but this lead to other errors. I feel like I was almost there then my VP tanked the whole project. so I wont be able to report if this solution actually worked or not but thanks a lot anyway. cheers!